# Fetch rows with MAX DATE and GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, database, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table name `payment_schedule` with following contents

[image: payment_schedule]

I want to fetch records with `MAX(due_date) GROUPED BY loan_application_id`

With reference to records in above image, i expect the result to be following

[image]

I tried using following SQL query

```
SELECT
    id,
    MAX(due_date) as due_date,
    loan_application_id
FROM
    payment_schedule
GROUP BY
    loan_application_id
```

Which returns me the following result.

[image]

As you see it does not return the corresponding `id` for a given due date.

Additionally, I have another column called `payment_type_id` and I need to exclude rows when `payment_type_id` has value of `3`.

I tried several solution available here, nothing seems to work, how to go about it?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, how about this query? SELECT
    id,
    MAX(due_date) as due_date,
    loan_application_id
FROM
    payment_schedule
GROUP BY
    loan_application_id,id

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called *Group-wise Maximum* and tagged here as [greatest-n-per-group](/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group).  The most traditional approach is to find the value you want and do a join to get the corresponding row per group like this:

```
SELECT
    ps.id,
    ps.due_date,
    ps.loan_application_id
FROM
(
    SELECT
        MAX(due_date) as due_date,
        loan_application_id
    FROM payment_schedule
    WHERE payment_type_id != '3'
    GROUP BY loan_application_id
) ps2
    LEFT JOIN payment_schedule ps USING (loan_application_id)
WHERE ps.due_date = ps2.due_date
    AND ps.payment_type_id != '3'
GROUP BY ps.loan_application_id
```

It's also worth mentioning that this query will run a bazillion times faster if you have an index on your `loan_application_id` and `due_date` columns.

Best discussion I've seen here on SO is this: [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/17338495)

Also addressed in the official docs here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Comment: Thanks, checking it out.

Comment: i revised my answer to mention this, but make sure you have indexes on the relevant columns.  it will make this a lot faster on large tables.

Answer (score 2):

If due date per loan_application_id is distinct, you can remove the keyword distinct below:

```
select distinct a.*
from payment_schedule a, (
    select loan_application_id, max(due_date) max_date
    from payment_schedule
    where payment_type_id <> 3
    group by 1
) as b
where a.loan_application_id = b.loan_application_id
and a.due_date = b.max_date
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, i forgot to add one more condition i.e i got another column called payment_type_id, i need to exclude rows when payment_type_id has value of 3

Comment: OK updated. if your payment_type_id got null value: use this one: where ifnull(payment_type_id,0)<>3

Answer (score 0):

In most databases, this is easiest using window functions.  In MySQL, you can use a `join` and `group by`:

```
select ps.*
from payment_schedule ps join
     (select load_application_id, max(due_date) as maxdd
      from payment_schedule
      group by load_application_id
     ) l
     on ps.load_application_id = l.load_application_id and ps.due_date = l.maxdd;
```

Comment: This gives me incorrect result, it returns 3 records, I have updated my question to reflect the result.

Comment: @IbrahimAzharArmar . . It was missing a join condition.